# Smarty inserts PHP function in <BODY> instead of inside <TD>

Tags: php, html, html-table, smarty

I have this simple PHP function in admin.php

```
function accountMenu()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
        { ?>
      <a href="update_profile.php">Update My Profile</a><br>
      <a href="update_email.php">Update My E-mail Address</a><br>
      <a href="logout.php">Logout </a>
    <?php }
}
```

I assign a variable to this function in dashboard.php

```
//smarty paths here

include 'admin.php';

$accountMenu = accountMenu();

$smarty->assign('accountMenu', $accountMenu);
$smarty->display('dashboard.tpl');
```

And try to display this via dashboard.tpl

```
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="main">
        <tr>
            <td width="160" valign="top">
            {$accountMenu}
            </td>
            <td width="732" valign="top">
                <h3>Dashboard</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

What happens is that the `accountMenu` elements are shown immediately after `<BODY>` (and even before `<TITLE>!`) and not within the `<TD>`.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `$smarty->assign('accountMenu', $accountMIenu);` Your variable is named incorrectly.

Comment: thanks Russel - but that typo is not in the original code, just corrected the code here on SO

Comment: so just to be clear, the problem still persists - elements going to BODY instead of TD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything - it simply outputs the HTML straight to the buffer, so when you call this:

```
$accountMenu = accountMenu();
```

It immediately prints it to the browser and $accountMenu remains NULL.

Change it so that it returns the desired string, for example:

```
function accountMenu()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) return '
      <a href="update_profile.php">Update My Profile</a><br>
      <a href="update_email.php">Update My E-mail Address</a><br>
      <a href="logout.php">Logout </a>
    ';
}
```